# File integrity monitoring in Samhain alerts on null change to permissions

Tags: monitoring

The problem:

Trying to get Samhain to give alerts on changes to files that should not change for security purposes.

This includes changes to file permissions. However (as the log shows, which is a subset of the 20k or so files that come up)

```
ALERT  :  [2023-06-02T15:29:22+0000] msg=<POLICY [IgnoreNone] -----M---->, path=</etc/xattr.conf>, mode_old=<-rw-r--r-->, mode_new=<-rw-r--r-->, attr_old=<------------>, attr_new=<------------>, owner_old=<root>, owner_new=<root>, iowner_old=<0>, iowner_new=<0>, group_old=<root>, group_new=<root>, igroup_old=<0>, igroup_new=<0>,
BD17E766EA09FCDC7691BD7058B472502BB825B38428AAF8
ALERT  :  [2023-06-02T15:29:22+0000] msg=<POLICY [IgnoreNone] -----M---->, path=</etc/wgetrc>, mode_old=<-rw-r--r-->, mode_new=<-rw-r--r-->, attr_old=<------------>, attr_new=<------------>, owner_old=<root>, owner_new=<root>, iowner_old=<0>, iowner_new=<0>, group_old=<root>, group_new=<root>, igroup_old=<0>, igroup_new=<0>,
```

As shown, `mode_old==mode_new`  yet we have these alerts.

The Question:

- How do I resolve this?
- Have I misunderstood what we're attempting to do here and misused it?